# Spring - Social - Hibernate: Unable to register / login as UserConnection is not mapped

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-security, spring-social

Working on trying to implement Spring Social aspects into a web app and having a few difficulties.

I'm using Postgresql, hibernate flavour of JPA and Spring with XML config.  I found a well recommended JAR that meant I could carry on using JPA.

Details are here : https://github.com/michaellavelle/spring-social-hibernate-jpa

Imported using maven, followed instructions and all seemed well. When selecting login with Facebook (I'm not using their sdk) I receive a 500 with the error:

```
    message org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: UserConnection is not mapped [select u from UserConnection u where u.primaryKey.providerId = :providerId and u.primaryKey.providerUserId = :providerUserId order by u.rank]

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: UserConnection is not mapped [select u from UserConnection u where u.primaryKey.providerId = :providerId and u.primaryKey.providerUserId = :providerUserId order by u.rank]
    org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
    org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:350)
```

The error itself seems fairly self explanatory, there is no UserConnection table in the DB which leads me to think I've configured something incorrectly as this is the responsibility of the library.

Or am I completely mistaken?  Any help is very much appreciated, would love to get this working.

EDIT:
Social.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:facebook="http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/facebook"
       xmlns:twitter="http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/twitter"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:social="http://www.springframework.org/schema/social"
       xmlns:linkedin="http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/linkedin"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/facebook
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/spring-social-facebook.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/linkedin
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/spring-social-linkedin.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/twitter
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/spring-social-twitter.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/social
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/spring-social.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">
```

```
<facebook:config app-id="${facebook.clientId}" app-secret="${facebook.clientSecret}" app-namespace="socialshowcase" />
<twitter:config app-id="${twitter.consumerKey}" app-secret="${twitter.consumerSecret}"/>
<linkedin:config app-id="${linkedin.consumerKey}" app-secret="${linkedin.consumerSecret}"/>

<!--<social:jdbc-connection-repository/>-->
<bean id="userIdSource" class="org.springframework.social.security.AuthenticationNameUserIdSource" />

<bean id="connectController" class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController" autowire="constructor">
    <property name="connectInterceptors">
        <list>
            <bean class="com.simpleSchedule.social.facebook.PostToWallAfterConnectInterceptor" />
            <!--<bean class="org.springframework.social.showcase.twitter.TweetAfterConnectInterceptor" />-->
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="usersConnectionRepository"
      class="org.springframework.social.connect.jpa.JpaUsersConnectionRepository">
    <constructor-arg ref="userConnectionDao" />
    <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactoryLocator" />
    <constructor-arg ref="textEncryptor" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.social.connect.jpa.JpaConnectionRepository"
        id="connectionRepository" factory-method="createConnectionRepository"
        factory-bean="usersConnectionRepository" scope="request">
    <constructor-arg value="#{request.userPrincipal.name}" />
    <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="true" />
</bean>


<bean id="psc" class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInController" autowire="constructor" />
<bean id="signInAdapter" class="com.simpleSchedule.social.singin.SimpleSignInAdapter" autowire="constructor" />

<bean id="disconnectController" class="org.springframework.social.facebook.web.DisconnectController"
    c:_0-ref="usersConnectionRepository" c:_1="${facebook.clientSecret}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Michael Lavelle very kindly replied to a comment I posted on gitbub.

The solution was to add `org.springframework.social.connect.jpa.hibernate.UserConnection` as a mapping in my persistence.xml.

Full details can be viewed at [the github issue](https://github.com/michaellavelle/spring-social-hibernate-jpa/issues/4)